# Does running a few miles daily makes you lose musculature?

Tags: bodybuilding

I have seen various bodybuilding sites claim that running releases cortisol which 'eats' away muscles.

Is this true?
Do muscles really get affected by running? Not talking about a marathon or any long distance event, but 2-3 miles a day.(I know running long distance events reduce your musculature)

Would it make me lose muscles?

But, Navy Seals do incorporate running a few miles daily in their schedules so there must be some benefits.

Comment: Odd they say that considering weightlifting releases cortisol too. This has been asked a few times.  https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/34346/can-you-effectively-put-on-mass-while-being-highly-active-fit/34350
https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/34599/is-running-almost-every-day-bad-during-a-bulking-phase/34602

Answer (score 1):

A mixture of cardiovascular training and strength training has been shown to minimize the effect of both cardiovascular progress and strength.
However mixing running or other cardio activities with hypertrophy training has shown no negative effect.

To maximize strength simply do cardio on separated days, for muscle growth you can mix them and rip all the benefits. Humans are built to have high stamina and endurance,that's why maximum strength effort doesn't go well back to back with cardio.

Comment: Hey,I didnt understand the second part, would you mind explaining it?